# Are my DB tables normalised to 3NF?

Tags: database, database-design, normalization, 3nf, third-normal-form

I need to make sure my schema is in 3NF, but am not too sure about my "StudentHomework Table" can someone help?

http://prntscr.com/6ry22u

Comment: Questions need to be self-contained, not just a link to an external resource, just like answers.

Comment: What is "marks" in the StudentHomework table? Can there be multiple ones? If that is the case, the StudentHomework table is not in normal form

Comment: No there can't be multiple ones, sorry didn't make that field name very clear, will change it right away.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The main concern I have with your approach is the lack of relation between Teacher and Subject.

The way I see it, a HomeworkTask should have a SubjectId, and the Subject should be taught by a Teacher.

So, I would do this. A new Table, Subject:

```
Table Subject:
Id (PK)
TeacherId (FK)
Name
Description
... any other fields necessary
```

Then, refactor HomeworkTask:

```
Table HomeworkTask:
Id (PK)
SubjectId (FK)
HomeworkTitle
SetDate
DueDate
```

Apart from this, you have clear Primary keys, all non prime attributes depend on the PKs and nothing but the PKs, so you should be home free for the 3rd normalization form.

Hope this helps. Cheers!